# Adding user defined types to an array

Tags: opa

I have defined a type called node along with a list of nodes.

```
type node = {name: string; description: string}
nodes = [] : list(node)
```

I have created a function called `createNewNode()` which creates a new node, assigns it to selectedNode, and adds it to the array nodes.

```
line 19: createNewNode() =
line 20:   selectedNode = {name="" remoteFSRoot=""} : node
line 21:   nodes = [nodes | selectedNode]
  ...
```

When I compile this I get the following error:

```
Error
File "node.opa", line 21, characters 10-32, (21:10-21:32 | 592-614)
Expression has type { hd: list(node); tl: node } / 'c.a but is coerced into
list('a).
Types { name: string; description: string } and
{ hd: 'a; tl: list('a) } / { nil } are not compatible
Hint:
  One of the sum types may be missing the following cases of the
  other:
  { nil }
  { hd tl }.
```

What does this compile message mean and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you simply inversed `nodes` and `selectedNode` at Line 21 :

```
nodes = [selectedNode | nodes]
```

Comment: Yep, it is always something simple :).  Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you want to be sure, you can also do : List.add(elt, mylist) or List.cons(elt, mylist)